# How to prefix image processing result with the name of the image in Python?

Tags: image-processing, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

```
def generalarea(self):
  for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif'):
    img = np.asarray(Image.open(filename).convert('L'))                            
    img = 1 * (img < 127)
    garea = (img == 0).sum()
    print garea

def areasplit(self):
  for filename in glob.iglob ('*.tif'):    
    img = np.asarray(Image.open(filename).convert('L'))                            
    img = 1 * (img < 127)
    areasplit = np.split(img.ravel(), 24) # here we are splitting converted to 1D array
  for i in areasplit:
   sarea = (i == 0).sum()
   print sarea
```

These two methods process .tif images in the working directory. I need to add the prefix IMAGENAME to the number result (to get like:  firstimage, 6786876876 or secondimage___67876876). How to implement that idea?

Answer (score 1):

For example, for the first function, instead of `print garea`, you could have:

```python
print "%s___%d" % (filename, garea)
```

or `"%s, %d"` if  you want a comma. See Python's doc on [string formatting operations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

the `%` style formatting will be deprecated, eventually....so they say .

It is better practice to use the new style ([doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec))

```
print "{fname}__{garea}".format(garea=garea, fname=filename)
```